# Joomla, assing menu-item to particular user

Tags: authentication, joomla, portfolio

I am designing a photographers website.
What i need to do is allow every logged in user to view -ONLY- his portfolio and no other.

Since i haven't found any extension that does that in style, i decided to use a general portfolio extension, and create a portfolio for each user.

Then i need to find a way so that when a user logs in, with his username/password, a menu-item will appear that will hold -ONLY- his portfolio.

So my question is, how can i do that???
Assign a single menuitem to a single user.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The only idea I have in mind is to use user groups here. Create the user, create the user group, assign the user to the group and assign that group to the object you want to protect.

If it's just about showing images I have another idea.

I build that user group specific handling into Event Gallery, a Joomla! gallery component: https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/photos-a-images/galleries/event-gallery/

Doing this make creating different menu items unnecessary. Once the user logs in he can see his content. In addition the content is protected. A simple menu item might not do that trick.